# Can I disable #include in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, file, include

I have been unable to find anything using *the google*...  If I write on my ASP.NET code page:

```
<!-- #include file="file_to_include.aspx" -->
```

the file is output to the page.  How do I disable this behavior?

---

MSDN info on [#include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525940.aspx) and [Server Side Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525185.aspx) (SSI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Even Newer Answer** *<sup>Now with More Cowbell!</sup>*

It turns out you can disable Server Side Includes in the **Web Service Extensions Manager** of IIS:
[image]

Just select `Server Side Includes` and click the `Prohibit` button.

**Answer #2**<sup>*Newer Answer*</sup>:

How about [disabling server side includes](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/serverSideInclude) in IIS?

---

**Old Answer**

If you use a [Server Side comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx), that should work.

Try this:

```
<%--  <!-- #include file="file_to_include.aspx" --> --%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm looking for a more global solution so that I can prevent this behavior totally.

Comment: ooo didn't know about serverside comments! hott

Comment: If you ever forget, you can use the comment-code keyboard shortcut in visual studio (ctrl-k, ctrl-u)

Comment: @Gortok - The command you're referencing there disables running a command line via #exec in Server Side Includes (SSI).  It does not however fully disable SSIs.

Comment: I added how to fully disable SSI.

Comment: @Gortok - Thank you fine sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar!